# Retrieving SQL View with Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view in my database called "viewUsers" that I need to operate on with my other entity generated tables.  How can I retrieve this database view in entity?

Comment: this must be pretty straight forward...when you set up your EDMX file in Entity Framework...you can select tables/Views/Stored Procedures...directly in the wizard...I am just wondering if you are trying to do anything different here...here is an example post that talks about importing views as entities in your project...http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/...let me know if this helped...

Answer (score 2):

In the Wizard, you can select Views. EF will take care of rest. Detailed example  [here](http://In%20the%20Wizard,%20you%20can%20select%20Views.%20EF%20will%20take%20care%20of%20rest.)

[image]

**EDIT :** As per the comment (how to do it in codefirst),

As of Entity Framework 4.2, Codefirst has built in support only for tables. That means It is only capable of generating schemas that contains tables. But If you are working with an existing database, You can map a an Updatable View with an entity. You can use the entity framework to select, insert, update and delete data.  This works same as of a table. Since the SQL syntax is same for table and view for these operations, **we are telling a lie to codefirst tha the view is a table!**

Ex : IF we want to get data from a View called `vwCustomerDetails` for the Entity called `CustomerDetail`, We can do like this with Data Annotations

```
[Table("vwCustomerDetails")]
public class CustomerDetail
{
  // properties
}
```

Alternatively, With Fluent API, you can do this,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDetail>().ToTable("vwCustomerDetails");
```

**Loading Data From a Normal View**

Sometime you may want to load some data from another view which returns the same result as of our initial fake table (the view). Ex : In some Page we need to show the top Ten CustomerDetails who scored highest points. Assume we have a separate View called `vwTop10Customers` for that. we can use the SqlQuery method on DBSet to load the entotues like this

```
var topCustomers=dbContext.CustomerDetails.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM  vwTop10Customers");
```

The View Must return the exact same column names as of the Entity. Otherwise EF will have a problem for mapping that.

Comment: I did a little research and it looks like .emdx does not work with code first.  Would I run a manual SQL query to return the view (as described here?  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application